# C++ error C2181: illegal else without matching if

Tags: c++

I'm new to C++. I have been following an online course that teaches you how to make a Hangman game in C++. For the most part the code was working, every time I debugged it ran fine. I completed the entire code and double checked it, but I'm getting an error on one of the 'else' the errors I'm getting is "error C2181: illegal else without matching if.

Here's my code.

```
// Hangman game
// CN

// Header file
#include "stdafx.h"
// Input/Output
#include <iostream>
// Text
#include <string>
// Information storage
#include <vector>
// Figuring out the information storage
#include <algorithm>
// Converts lower cased letters to higher case letters
#include <cctype>
// Reads computers time and distributes a word from a list accordingly
#include <ctime>
// Library for system
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;


int main()
{
    // Constant data type which is a fixed value, MaxWrong in Pascal Text and the max number of guesses.
    const int MaxWrong = 6;


    vector<string> words;
    words.push_back("SANTA CLAUSE");
    words.push_back("REINDEER");
    words.push_back("PRESENT");
    words.push_back("TREE");
    words.push_back("MILK");
    words.push_back("COOKIE");

    // Parenthesis must always match
    srand(static_cast<unsigned int>(time(0)));
    random_shuffle(words.begin(), words.end());
    const string theWord = words[0];
    int wrong = 0;
    string soFar(theWord.size(), '_');
    string used = "";

    cout << "\n******** Welcome to Chaye's Hangman ********\n\n";
    cout << "      __  \n";
    cout << "     |  | \n";
    cout << "     |    \n";
    cout << "     |    \n";
    cout << "     |    \n";
    cout << "     |    \n";
    cout << "  ___|____  \n\n";
    cout << " Do Your Best Human  \n\n";

    // Loop
    while ((wrong < MaxWrong) && (soFar != theWord))
    {
        cout << "\n You have " << (MaxWrong - wrong);
        cout << " incorrect tries left.\n";
        cout << "\n You've used these letters:\n" << used << endl;

        char guess;
        cout << "\n\n Enter your guess: ";
        cin >> guess;
        guess = toupper(guess);
        while (used.find(guess) != string::npos)
        {
            cout << "\n You've already tried " << guess << endl;
            cout << " Enter your guess: ";
            cin >> guess;
            guess = toupper(guess);
        }

        used += guess;

        if (theWord.find(guess) != string::npos)
        {
            cout << " That's right " << guess << " is in the word,\n";

            for (int i = 0; i < theWord.length(); ++i)
            {
                if (theWord[i] == guess)
                {
                    soFar[i] = guess;
                }
            }
        }

        else
        {
            cout << " sorry. " << guess << " isn't in the word.\n";
            ++wrong;
        }


        // If one is wrong
        if (wrong == 1)
        {
            cout << "      __  \n";
            cout << "     |  | \n";
            cout << "     |  O \n";
            cout << "     |    \n";
            cout << "     |    \n";
            cout << "     |    \n";
            cout << "  ___|____  \n\n";
            cout << " Do Your Best Human  \n\n";
        }
        else
        {
            cout << endl;
        }

        // If one is wrong
        if (wrong == 2)
        {
            cout << "      ___  \n";
            cout << "     |   | \n";
            cout << "     |   O \n";
            cout << "     |   @ \n";
            cout << "     |    \n";
            cout << "     |    \n";
            cout << "  ___|____  \n\n";
            cout << " Do Your Best Human  \n\n";
        }
        else
        {
            cout << endl;
        }


        // If one is wrong
        if (wrong == 3)
        {
            cout << "      ___  \n";
            cout << "     |   | \n";
            cout << "     |   O \n";
            cout << "     |  /@ \n";
            cout << "     |     \n";
            cout << "     |     \n";
            cout << "  ___|____  \n\n";
            cout << " Do Your Best Human  \n\n";
        }
        else
        {
            cout << endl;
        }

        // If one is wrong
        if (wrong == 4)
        {
            cout << "      ___   \n";
            cout << "     |   |  \n";
            cout << "     |   O  \n";
            cout << "     |  /@\ \n";
            cout << "     |      \n";
            cout << "     |      \n";
            cout << "  ___|____  \n\n";
            cout << " Do Your Best Human  \n\n";
        }
        else
        {
            cout << endl;
        }

        // If one is wrong
        if (wrong == 5)
        {
            cout << "\n You've been hung  \n";
            cout << "      ___   \n";
            cout << "     |   |  \n";
            cout << "     |   O  \n";
            cout << "     |  /@\ \n";
            cout << "     |  /   \n";
            cout << "     |      \n";
            cout << "  ___|____  \n\n";
            cout << " Do Your Best Human  \n\n";
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "\n I'm suprised you've got this far\n";
        }
        cout << "\n The word was " << theWord << endl;


    }

    // If one is wrong
    if (wrong == MaxWrong)
    {
        cout << "\n You've been hung  \n";
        cout << "      ___   \n";
        cout << "     |   |  \n";
        cout << "     |   O  \n";
        cout << "     |  /@\ \n";
        cout << "     |  / \  \n";
        cout << "     |      \n";
        cout << "  ___|____  \n\n";
        cout << " Do Your Best Human  \n\n";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "\n I'm suprised you've got this far\n";
    }
    cout << "\n The word was " << theWord << endl;


    // Pause Console
    system("pause");

    // Kills the application once done
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I suggest you read a good book on C++, such as `C++ Primer`

Answer (score 1):

There should be no semicolon in this line:

```
if (theWord.find(guess) != string::npos);
```

this semicolon terminates the whole if statement and the following `{...}` block is executed unconditionally. Following `else` is therefore no longer matched with the if statement.

And you are also missing closing `)` bracket in your while statement:

```
while (used.find(guess) != string::npos
{
...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! I've deleted the semi colon, it's removed the 'system' is ambiguous error and the expected a statement error, however the illegal else error still persists.

Comment: You are also missing a closing bracket in your while statement, see edit.

Comment: Ah, thanks, I accidentally deleted the bracket when I removed the semi colon, my bad, thanks for the time and patience you've given me.

Comment: And you must have forgotten removing it, because the code compiles without it.

Comment: Any idea what's causing the error C2181: illegal else without matching if?

Answer (score -2):

Change

```
** else **
```

to

```
else
```

Your compiler is interpreting that as an operator.  If it still fails, edit your post w/ the error.  Also worth noting, if you compile w/ the -g flag you get some debug output which can be beneficial.

Comment: OP says they've "marked" the problem spot. Those `**` aren't in their real code.

Comment: I only added the asterisks on hereto try and save people time, by showing which one I was getting the error on. I'll just remove it.

Comment: I see that now -- wasn't quite as obvious to me when reading. :-/

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I'm a bit new at all of this, thanks for your time in helping me though!

Comment: No problem.  Try the -g flag.  Output depends on your compiler but it can help a lot.

Comment: Any idea what's causing the error C2181: illegal else without matching if?

Comment: I don't -- I copy/pasted your code and it compiled and ran just fine.

Comment: Thank you, I found it what it was, I had a little comment code underneath all of this I had forgot about which had a curly bracket  in it, thank you all for your help.